# How to use subreport in jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

What have I done wrong here?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    subreport_dir = "...\\Report\\subReport.jasper";
    try {            
        compileView("...\\Report\\myReport.jrxml");            
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No Row");
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

when I call the function

```
private static void compileView(String path) throws JRException {
    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("month", myMonth);
    param.put("year", myYear);
    param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subreport_dir);
    param.putAll(param);
    JasperReport jRp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
    JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jRp, param, getConnection());
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jPrint, false);
    JasperViewer.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

}
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change the language tag in your report on the `<jasperReport>` tag

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="6afeba62-b470-4dfb-a8fb-42e2226b906d">
```

**language="groovy"**

to

**language="java"**